# Can you meet caster level requirements with conditional bonuses?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, feats, spheres-of-power, caster-level

I am playing a level 8 Incanter from Spheres of Power. As a full caster, this gives me a caster level of 8. I have a trait which increases my caster level for the destruction sphere by 1, and I have a stave of destruction (+1). This gives me a total CL of 10 in destruction. This has allowed me to qualify for the Wand Wielder feat, which requires a CL of 10 or higher.

Am I only allowed to use the feat when I'm wielding the staff (so I would be wielding both a stave and wand to benefit at the moment), or am I just allowed to have the stave on me?

Comment: Your title question [has been answered before](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/96010/4563), but I have reworded the title to match the body better, since you have the special case of only receiving a conditional bonus.

Comment: Would you mind if we found a different, 1st-party example to use here? This is a good, general-interest question that a lot of people might need the answer to, and I worry about *Spheres of Power* introducing a red herring and leading people to think that this question doesn’t apply to them. *Spheres of Power* has lots of new rules, but this isn’t one of them. Normally I would say it’s best to limit tags from particular products to questions that really are about the new rules from those rulesets, rather than things that just happened to be in them but are using the core rules.

Comment: @KRyan Expect for some Ioun stones, I dont know of any items that increase CL so how could you modify the question to work? The question is about when the feat is active with the staff, in hand or on person.

Comment: Caster level bonuses to specific types of spells are not that uncommon, I’d be surprised if there aren’t several items we could use. I will look when I get home.

Comment: @KRyan Did you find any other sources?

Answer (score 2):

Wand Wielder requires caster level 10th—not caster level 10th *with destruction*, which is what you have. The fact that these bonuses come from traits or items or anything else is irrelevant; [you could meet the requirement just fine using those things](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/96010/4563). But the bonuses you are receiving are not giving you the bonuses you need to meet the prerequisite. You cannot select or use Wand Wielder.